# Debian boot messages are missing from the console

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I'm working on a custom ARM board, for which I'm using a dirty kernel. I've build a root filesystem using wheezy (debian 7.2) armhf. I can see the debian boot log messages when I boot this root file system in Qemu (qemu-system-arm). I don't see them either on the framebuffer of the ARM board, or the serial console. console= is properly set in the kernel commandline, and I do see the kernel log messages when the system boots up.

What kernel config option, if any, could be causing this? I'm working to clean up this kernel I have and make it non dirty. Or is there a Debian config that governs the log behaviour? I have tried putting VERBOSE in /etc/default/rcS

I've already tried putting verbose and debug on the commandline. Installing bootlogd didn't help either - the boot log (/var/log/boot) turned up empty.

Comment: What command line parameter passing to kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at all these options:

1. Check that serial console is enabled (see in Device Drivers -> Character Devices -> Serial Drivers in the kernel configuration)
2. Check that specific serial driver is enabled in the kernel configuration
3. Check that **console=xxx** is set among kernel boot options (it can be either on U-Boot **bootargs** option or hardcoded in the kernel configuration)
4. Check that **debug** is set among kernel boot options (it can be either on U-Boot **bootargs** option or hardcoded in the kernel configuration)

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-activate-bootlogd-or-capture-bootup-messages-the-current-modern-way-4175443039/) `grep -rn PTY sysvinit-2.88dsf/` confirmed that hint

> sysvinit-2.88dsf/man/bootlogd.8:60:(Consequently \fBbootlogd\fP requires PTY support in the kernel configuration.)

So `CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS` should be set in the kernel configuration, which is currently not

> 2831:# CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS is not set

Answer (score 0):

1. systemctl disable lightdm
2. /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "text"
3. update-grub

it is like --noclear